# How navigate multiple stack without seeing other stack animation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How can I navigate between multiple stack without this animation?

[problem http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=19/15/cma6.gif](http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=19/15/cma6.gif)

Yes my architecture is like this :

```
Screen A
Screen B
Screen C
Screen D 
     Screen D1
     Screen D2
```

I would like to go back from the screen D2 to the screen B.
I already tried 'Reset' but it removes the animation

Answer (score 0):

```
const StackNavigatorConfig = {
  [...]
  transitionConfig : () => ({
    transitionSpec: {
        duration: 0,
        timing: Animated.timing,
        easing: Easing.step0,
    },
  }),
}

export const Navigator = StackNavigator(RouteConfiguration,StackNavigatorConfig)
```

You need to send duration to 0 while pushing to new screen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i would like to keep animation when i push a new screen